# Wireless network is not available after apt upgrade

Tags: networking, network-manager, internet, laptop

I am using ubuntu laptop. (Think pad t14s gen2)
I updated package recently.
And then, now I couldn't access internet using wifi.
The only way I can access the Internet is through my cell phone hotspot.
It's strange that I can't connect through my home Wi-Fi, but I can connect through my phone's hotspot. Strange but this is real.
There is no problem with the home network.  And even I tried connecting to another Wi-Fi, such as a cafe, but the result was the same.

Are there any suspicious circumstances?

```
  *-network
       description: Wireless interface
       product: MT7921 802.11ax PCI Express Wireless Network Adapter
       vendor: MEDIATEK Corp.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       logical name: wlp3s0
       logical name: /dev/fb0
       version: 00
       serial: **:**:**:**
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pciexpress msi pm bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless fb
       configuration: broadcast=yes depth=32 driver=mt7921e driverversion=6.5.0-14-generic firmware=____010000-20220209150915 ip=192.168.58.29 latency=0 link=yes mode=1920x1080 multicast=yes visual=truecolor wireless=IEEE 802.11 xres=1920 yres=1080
       resources: iomemory:40-3f iomemory:40-3f iomemory:40-3f irq:94 memory:470200000-4702fffff memory:470300000-470303fff memory:470304000-470304fff
```